# 2006 Jeep Grand Cherokee 3.7l shifting issues

Tags: shifting

So my Jeep has been shifting late/taking forever to shift, even in the auto stick mode. It tales a good 8-10 second to shift. It absolutely hates hills which is bad because i live in southern Indiana which is nothing but hills. It will also surge sometimes, i can definitely tell because I have an aftermarket exhaust so I can hear it surge. I put transmission fluid in it and it doesn't do it for a about 60 miles then it does it again

Comment: Are you losing fluid? I had similar issue, not on a  jeep. Found a metal transmission fluid cooling line had corrosion and a tiny leak. Over a week or so i would lose enogh fluid to have presure changes and delayed shifts that would hit hard, when they finally do happen. Checked for leaks?